# problem with one symbolic link

Tags: cuda, symbolic-link

Really I am a noob in Ubuntu. I have a problem, getting this warning each time I try to update my distribution which is 17.10. the error I get is as follows

```
/sbin/ldconfig.real: /usr/local/cuda-8.0/lib64/libcudnn.so.6 is not a symbolic link
```

how can I solve it?
here it is ls -l in that folder

```
/usr/local/cuda-8.0/lib64$ ls -l
total 1707224
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  53464088 نوامب  1 13:08 libcublas_device.a
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root        16 نوامب  1 13:08 libcublas.so -> libcublas.so.8.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root        19 نوامب  1 13:09 libcublas.so.8.0 -> libcublas.so.8.0.61
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  42505456 نوامب  1 13:08 libcublas.so.8.0.61
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  49080634 نوامب  1 13:09 libcublas_static.a
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    556000 نوامب  1 13:09 libcudadevrt.a
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root        16 نوامب  1 13:08 libcudart.so -> libcudart.so.8.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root        19 نوامب  1 13:09 libcudart.so.8.0 -> libcudart.so.8.0.61
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    415432 نوامب  1 13:09 libcudart.so.8.0.61
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    775162 نوامب  1 13:09 libcudart_static.a
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 154322864 نوامب  1 17:04 libcudnn.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 154322864 نوامب  1 17:04 libcudnn.so.6
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 154322864 نوامب  1 17:04 libcudnn.so.6.0.21
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 143843808 نوامب  1 17:04 libcudnn_static.a
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root        15 نوامب  1 13:08 libcufft.so -> libcufft.so.8.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root        18 نوامب  1 13:09 libcufft.so.8.0 -> libcufft.so.8.0.61
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 146765440 نوامب  1 13:09 libcufft.so.8.0.61
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 129661426 نوامب  1 13:09 libcufft_static.a
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root        16 نوامب  1 13:08 libcufftw.so -> libcufftw.so.8.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root        19 نوامب  1 13:09 libcufftw.so.8.0 -> libcufftw.so.8.0.61
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    476840 نوامب  1 13:09 libcufftw.so.8.0.61
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     42294 نوامب  1 13:09 libcufftw_static.a
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root        17 نوامب  1 13:08 libcuinj64.so -> libcuinj64.so.8.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root        20 نوامب  1 13:08 libcuinj64.so.8.0 -> libcuinj64.so.8.0.61
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   6403784 نوامب  1 13:09 libcuinj64.so.8.0.61
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   1649302 نوامب  1 13:09 libculibos.a
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root        16 نوامب  1 13:08 libcurand.so -> libcurand.so.8.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root        19 نوامب  1 13:09 libcurand.so.8.0 -> libcurand.so.8.0.61
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  59163968 نوامب  1 13:09 libcurand.so.8.0.61
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  59359140 نوامب  1 13:08 libcurand_static.a
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root        18 نوامب  1 13:08 libcusolver.so -> libcusolver.so.8.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root        21 نوامب  1 13:09 libcusolver.so.8.0 -> libcusolver.so.8.0.61
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  53866552 نوامب  1 13:09 libcusolver.so.8.0.61
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  22386284 نوامب  1 13:09 libcusolver_static.a
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root        18 نوامب  1 13:09 libcusparse.so -> libcusparse.so.8.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root        21 نوامب  1 13:08 libcusparse.so.8.0 -> libcusparse.so.8.0.61
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  43034120 نوامب  1 13:09 libcusparse.so.8.0.61
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  51650816 نوامب  1 13:08 libcusparse_static.a
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root        14 نوامب  1 13:09 libnppc.so -> libnppc.so.8.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root        17 نوامب  1 13:09 libnppc.so.8.0 -> libnppc.so.8.0.61
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    456512 نوامب  1 13:09 libnppc.so.8.0.61
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     24512 نوامب  1 13:09 libnppc_static.a
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root        16 نوامب  1 13:08 libnppial.so -> libnppial.so.8.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root        19 نوامب  1 13:09 libnppial.so.8.0 -> libnppial.so.8.0.61
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  10116032 نوامب  1 13:08 libnppial.so.8.0.61
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root        16 نوامب  1 13:08 libnppicc.so -> libnppicc.so.8.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root        19 نوامب  1 13:08 libnppicc.so.8.0 -> libnppicc.so.8.0.61
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   3790368 نوامب  1 13:09 libnppicc.so.8.0.61
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root        17 نوامب  1 13:08 libnppicom.so -> libnppicom.so.8.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root        20 نوامب  1 13:09 libnppicom.so.8.0 -> libnppicom.so.8.0.61
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   1030800 نوامب  1 13:09 libnppicom.so.8.0.61
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root        17 نوامب  1 13:08 libnppidei.so -> libnppidei.so.8.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root        20 نوامب  1 13:09 libnppidei.so.8.0 -> libnppidei.so.8.0.61
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   7098600 نوامب  1 13:09 libnppidei.so.8.0.61
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root        15 نوامب  1 13:08 libnppif.so -> libnppif.so.8.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root        18 نوامب  1 13:09 libnppif.so.8.0 -> libnppif.so.8.0.61
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  47868176 نوامب  1 13:09 libnppif.so.8.0.61
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root        15 نوامب  1 13:09 libnppig.so -> libnppig.so.8.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root        18 نوامب  1 13:08 libnppig.so.8.0 -> libnppig.so.8.0.61
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  21052640 نوامب  1 13:08 libnppig.so.8.0.61
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root        15 نوامب  1 13:09 libnppim.so -> libnppim.so.8.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root        18 نوامب  1 13:08 libnppim.so.8.0 -> libnppim.so.8.0.61
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   4333920 نوامب  1 13:08 libnppim.so.8.0.61
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root        14 نوامب  1 13:08 libnppi.so -> libnppi.so.8.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root        17 نوامب  1 13:08 libnppi.so.8.0 -> libnppi.so.8.0.61
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 108924816 نوامب  1 13:08 libnppi.so.8.0.61
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 136645168 نوامب  1 13:09 libnppi_static.a
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root        16 نوامب  1 13:09 libnppist.so -> libnppist.so.8.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root        19 نوامب  1 13:08 libnppist.so.8.0 -> libnppist.so.8.0.61
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  14270440 نوامب  1 13:09 libnppist.so.8.0.61
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root        16 نوامب  1 13:09 libnppisu.so -> libnppisu.so.8.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root        19 نوامب  1 13:08 libnppisu.so.8.0 -> libnppisu.so.8.0.61
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    448016 نوامب  1 13:09 libnppisu.so.8.0.61
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root        16 نوامب  1 13:09 libnppitc.so -> libnppitc.so.8.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root        19 نوامب  1 13:08 libnppitc.so.8.0 -> libnppitc.so.8.0.61
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   2897184 نوامب  1 13:09 libnppitc.so.8.0.61
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root        14 نوامب  1 13:09 libnpps.so -> libnpps.so.8.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root        17 نوامب  1 13:08 libnpps.so.8.0 -> libnpps.so.8.0.61
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   8178184 نوامب  1 13:08 libnpps.so.8.0.61
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  10741440 نوامب  1 13:09 libnpps_static.a
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root        16 نوامب  1 13:08 libnvblas.so -> libnvblas.so.8.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root        19 نوامب  1 13:08 libnvblas.so.8.0 -> libnvblas.so.8.0.61
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    498088 نوامب  1 13:09 libnvblas.so.8.0.61
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root        17 نوامب  1 13:09 libnvgraph.so -> libnvgraph.so.8.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root        20 نوامب  1 13:09 libnvgraph.so.8.0 -> libnvgraph.so.8.0.61
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   5213656 نوامب  1 13:09 libnvgraph.so.8.0.61
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   8169056 نوامب  1 13:09 libnvgraph_static.a
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root        24 نوامب  1 13:08 libnvrtc-builtins.so -> libnvrtc-builtins.so.8.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root        27 نوامب  1 13:08 libnvrtc-builtins.so.8.0 -> libnvrtc-builtins.so.8.0.61
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   9656680 نوامب  1 13:08 libnvrtc-builtins.so.8.0.61
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root        15 نوامب  1 13:09 libnvrtc.so -> libnvrtc.so.8.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root        18 نوامب  1 13:08 libnvrtc.so.8.0 -> libnvrtc.so.8.0.61
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  18512120 نوامب  1 13:08 libnvrtc.so.8.0.61
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root        18 نوامب  1 13:08 libnvToolsExt.so -> libnvToolsExt.so.1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root        22 نوامب  1 13:09 libnvToolsExt.so.1 -> libnvToolsExt.so.1.0.0
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root     37136 نوامب  1 13:09 libnvToolsExt.so.1.0.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root        14 نوامب  1 13:09 libOpenCL.so -> libOpenCL.so.1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root        16 نوامب  1 13:09 libOpenCL.so.1 -> libOpenCL.so.1.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root        18 نوامب  1 13:09 libOpenCL.so.1.0 -> libOpenCL.so.1.0.0
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     25840 نوامب  1 13:08 libOpenCL.so.1.0.0
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root      4096 نوامب  1 12:14 stubs
```

Comment: please supply `ls -l` to see if it is

Comment: Added what you mentioned

Comment: OK- it is a symbolic link. can you describe what do you try to do ?

Comment: @Guy. D it is not a symlink.

Comment: l indicates link

Comment: It does look unusual - I would have expected `libcudnn.so` to be a symbolic link to `libcudnn.so.6` which is then in turn a symbolic link to the specific version `libcudnn.so.so.6.0.21`. Instead they look (based on filesize) like copies. However maybe CUDA has its own reasons for doing that?

Comment: @guy as you know 17.10 use gnome which has changed the window control buttons position (close , maximize,minimize) to right. I wanted to have them in left. Simply I ran this code     
    `gconftool --type string --set/desktop/gnome/shell/windows/button_layout "close:"`
and then this code
    `sudo ldconfig`
which results in the following warning:
     `/sbin/ldconfig.real: /usr/local/cuda-8.0/lib64/libcudnn.so.6 is not a symbolic link`

Comment: @V.Ajall since I upgraded to 17 jusy for few days ( to many childhood bugs...) I don't recall the control buttons position, but do you see any relevance to the question above ?

Comment: The relevance is that last code doesn't execute due to the problem asked in the question above.

Comment: my problem solved I didn't know it is such like eating a peach, easier than drinking water to have these control buttons on the left position in ubuntu 17.10

Comment: now I want to know if it is possible if i can delete this warning each time I update my OS is it possible?